# VBA - Error handling with multiple forms

Tags: forms, vba

My application has several forms which call each other. I ran into a problem with error handling and since the project is too large to post here, I created the smallest subset of the code that still reproduces the problem. The file can be found [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ym2cxhxsqqpb39g/so_error_hadnlign_with_forms.xlsm?dl=0)

Components of the problem:

1. `raiseError` - a function that simply raises an error
2. `mainForm` - a form with one button - upon being clicked opens up `addClientForm`
3. `addClientForm` - a form which raises the error via `raiseError`
4. `showMainForm` - a caller which shows a `mainForm`

The code is really simple,

**Module Error**

```
Public Sub raiseError()
  Call Err.Raise(2048, "errorSource", "errorDescription")
End Sub
```

**MainForm**

```
Private Sub cbAddClientForm_Click()
  Dim xAddClientForm As New addClientForm: Call xAddClientForm.Show
End Sub
```

**AddClientForm**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  Call raiseError
End Sub
```

**Caller**

```
Public Sub caller()
  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

  Dim xMainForm As New mainForm: Call xMainForm.Show

ErrorExit:
  Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
  Call MsgBox("Error appeared", vbOKOnly)
  On Error Resume Next
  GoTo ErrorExit

End Sub
```

The `caller` shows a `mainForm` and once the user clicks the button, an `addClientForm` is initialized which causes a call to `raiseError`. The problem is that `ErrorHandler` in `caller` does not catch the error! Instead, the error raised in `raiseError` is treated as an unhandled error! That means that an ugly messageBox comes up and shoves the user right into the code in VBEditor - this is what I want to avoid.

I fiddled around with various setups of this problem and as long as there is not a sequence of forms where one calls the other, the error handling works as expected. In the attached file, all investigations are written into different modules along with the tested hypothesis.

So the questions are

1. Why is this happening
2. How can this be solved, i.e. how can I trap error raised by forms such that the user is not thrown into VBEditor?

ANY help or workaround is MUCH appreciated.
Daniel

Comment: I think you're suffering from [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26589039/3198973). The short answer, is don't raise errors in the Class_Initalize() event procedure.

Comment: @RubberDuck: Thank you for a reply, however, when I put a button onto the `addClientForm` and raise the error only in this button's _Click event, the behaviour is still the same - the error appears as unhandled.

Comment: @DanielBencik verify your options, in the [General] tab, in the [Error Handling] section - make sure "Break on Unhandled Errors" is checked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't say for certain *why* this is happening. I can't quite grok it myself, but there is a bit of a work around. You can declare the `ClientForm` [WithEvents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12152945/3198973) and catch the errors there by listening for a custom `OnError` event that gets raised from within the `ClientForm` itself. Note that you can't do this for the `MainForm` because you can't declare a variable `WithEvents` inside of a module. It has to be a class.

The big downfall here is that you need to manually redirect errors in the client form to it's `OnError` event and then have a Event procedure for each client form that you expect to handle errors from. The other downfall is [you can't "hear" events raised in the `Class_Intialize` event procedure.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26589039/3198973)

So, all in all, you may want to consider handling any errors locally in the client form.

**Module1**

```
Public Sub caller()

  Dim xMainForm As New MainForm
  xMainForm.Show

End Sub
```

**MainForm**

```
Option Explicit

Private WithEvents xClientForm As ClientForm

Private Sub cbAddClientForm_Click()

    Set xClientForm = New ClientForm
    xClientForm.Show

End Sub

Private Sub xClientForm_OnError(Err As ErrObject)
    MsgBox Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description & vbNewLine & Err.Source & " raised an error.", vbCritical, "Error"
End Sub
```

**ClientForm**

```
Option Explicit

Public Event OnError(Err As ErrObject)

Private Sub UserForm_Click()
On Error GoTo ErrHandler:

    raiseError

Exit Sub

ErrHandler:
    RaiseEvent OnError(Err)
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ' can't raise events from initialize, they won't be "heard"
    ' https://stackoverflow.com/q/26589039/3198973
End Sub

Public Sub raiseError()
  Err.Raise 2048, TypeName(Me), "errorDescription"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for this. The code works, it is something totally new to me, but it is exactly like you're saying, I will rewrite my code to handle errors locally in each form.